# Where are dotnet tool versions defined?

Tags: .net, .net-core, dotnet-tool, coverlet

How is are dotnet tools versioned and where is that version number set in code?

The latest version of this dotnet tool is 1.7.0 https://github.com/tonerdo/coverlet

Where is 1.7.0 defined? I don't see it anywhere and it's not the assembly version.

I want to install an older version but I can't find any dotnet commands that list previous versions of a tool.

Specifically, I need a version of coverlet that supports netcoreapp2.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

God what a mess.

- dotnet tools are just nuget packages (suppose I should have known that)
- dotnet command has some but not all overlap with nuget.exe (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/install-nuget-client-tools)
- so need nuget.exe to list packages
- but wait that functionality to list versions of a package is broken (for 5 years?!): https://github.com/NuGet/NuGetGallery/issues/3274, https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/3441
- sooo go to the website: https://www.nuget.org/packages/coverlet.console/

Success:

[image]